# Is there a way to make the subjects in an array clickable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm wanting to make a game using javascript. And part of the game is that there is a 'shop' and the user can click on things in the shop and it effects the score.

```
var i;
var shop = new Array();
shop[0] = "Bins:" + "  " + "5";
shop[1] = "Shops:" + "  " + "60";
shop[2] = "Factories: " + "   " + "190";
shop[3] = "Warehouses:" + "   " + "600";
shop[4] = "Over sies:" + "   " + "1,500";

for (i=0; i<shop.length; i++){
  document.write(shop[i] + "<br>")
}
```

That's what the array(s) look like, so would it be possible for a user to click on the object in the 'shop' and for it to effect the overall score of the game?

Comment: Why are you creating them dynamically? It would be better if you create them statically, right?

Comment: Why, thefourtheye? What if he loaded items with an Ajax call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make what's inside an array subject to be clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906745/is-there-a-way-to-make-whats-inside-an-array-subject-to-be-clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a simple js/html thing. To get you rolling, here is what you can try.

```
// First, define the array in a bit more data-friendly way.
var i, itemEl, valueEl, liEl, qty, totalScore, shop = [];
shop.push({item: 'Bins', quantity: 5});
shop.push({item: 'Shops', quantity: 60});
shop.push({item: 'Factories', quantity: 60190);
shop.push({item: 'Warehouses', quantity: 600});
shop.push({item: 'Over sies', quantity: 1500});

// then, create a javascript handler for clicks. It will increase the total score
totalScore = 0;
function addToScore(val) {
    totalScore += val;
    alert('New score: ' + totalScore);
}

// finally, output this as HTML. Find an UL element and add each item row.
var itemsContainer = document.getElementById('items');

for (i = 0; i < shop.length; i++) {
    // for each shop item, create a text node holding the label
    // and a clickable span containing the number. When the user clicks on the number
    // the totalScore increasing method will be called.
    // you can add other html elements like this, like
    // decreasing score, removing the item, whatever
    itemEl = document.createTextNode(shop[i].item + ': ');
    valueEl = document.createElement('span');
    valueEl.setAttribute('onclick', 'addToScore(' + shop[i].quantity + ')');
    liEl = document.createElement('li');
    liEl.appendChild(itemEl);
    liEl.appendChild(valueEl);
    itemsContainer.appendChild(liEl);
}
```

Your HTML should only contain the itemsContainer, like an <ul> element.

```
<ul id='items'></ul>
```

This is just an example. There are a few things not done "properly" there, but the code will work. And as you start with this, you'll learn other stuff and then come back and ask how to improve your code.