# Is there a way to make what's inside an array subject to be clicked?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a game that's similar to the game 'Cookie clicker' and I was wondering if there was a way to make what is in an array clickable, ie, like a shop, where there are different items that the user can click and it effects the score.

```
var i;
var shop = new Array();
shop[0] = "Bins:" + "  " + "5";
shop[1] = "Shops:" + "  " + "100";
shop[2] = "Factories: " + "   " + "500";
shop[3] = "Warehouses:" + "   " + "2,000";
shop[4] = "Over seas:" + "   " + "8,000";

for (i=0; i<shop.length; i++){
  document.write(shop[i] + "<br>")
}
```

The above is the array that stores what would be in the shop and the prices for the items. I'm finding it hard to find out how to make those items clickable and to make them effect the score.

Comment: There's too much to explain... You need to read about the basics of Javascript, HTML, event handling, responding to click events etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Conor's answer a bit, here is the solution done in a loop for each 'shop' -

http://jsfiddle.net/uLyJu/10/

You should really be using an array of objects and not just strings as you're really storing two things for each shop, a name and a value.  That will let you use each independently.

```
var shops = new Array();
shops[0] = { name: "Bins:", value: 5 };
shops[1] = { name: "Shops:", value: 100 };
shops[2] = { name: "Factories:", value: 500 };
shops[3] = { name: "Warehouses:", value: 2000 };
shops[4] = { name: "Over seas:", value: 8000 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign an event and event handler.  You should also include an ID attribute for each element so you can tell them apart.

Here is one example.

First give an ID for the HTML element representing a shop item

```
document.write('<div id="bins">'+shop[0]+'</div><br>');
```

Then you can select that element by it's ID and attach an event listener and handler.

```
var bins = document.getElementById("bins");
bins.addEventListener("click", function(eventData){
    //This is the event handler
    //this code will get executed when the bins element is clicked.
    console.log('Bins was clicked.  Here is some additional information ', eventData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create two arrays with `items` and `prices` that coordinate with each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/8pZsy/

You could also use a two dimensional array, which would accomplish the same thing.

JS

```
$(function() {loadItems();});

var totalcash=100;

function loadItems(){
var items = new Array();
var prices = new Array();

items[0]="Bins";
prices[0]=5;

items[1]="Shops";
prices[1]=100;

var output="<table border=1>";
  for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    output+="<tr><td><a href='javascript:D("+String(prices[i])+")'>"+items[i]+"</a>    </td><td>"+prices[i]+"</td></tr>";
  }
  output+="</table>";
  $("#output").html(output);
}

function D(price) {
  totalcash-=Number(price);
}
```

If you wanted shop to be a single entity, you could create a class to handle all such events. Using this object oriented (like) style allows you to keep your code concise and straightforward. With a game similar to this, you're likely to run into many different entities that all need handled differently

```
var shop = function(){

   this.createShop(){//create and output shop here}

   this.getPrice(item){//get price of a given item}

   this.chargeUser(price){//deduct user's total cash from given price}

   //
}
```